# React axios get data from JSON by object unique name

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, get, axios

I have a structure like this:

```
{
    "RESTAPI": {
        "uniqueId": {
            "id": "1",
            "data_2": "data_2",
            "data_3": true,
            "mg_gateway": "Another Object"
        }, 
        "uniqueId2": {
            "id": "1",
            "data_2": "data_2",
            "data_3": true,
            "mg_gateway": "Another Object"
        }
    }
}
```

`uniqueId` can be with letters and numbers. I try to get it:

```
componentDidMount() {
    axios.get('https:LINKNAME/RESTAPI.json')
        .then(res => {
            const fetched = res.data;
            this.setState({ data: fetched });
        })
}
```

And show in JSX:

```
{Object.keys(this.state.data).map((obj, i) => {
    return <p key={i}>{obj}</p>
})}
```

In browser I can see only strings (typeof string): **uniqueId** and **uniqueId2**
But in console log I get all Objects. 
 [console.log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lc1I9.png)

But I cant show data inside each nested Object in map. So I try to use `obj.data_2` and got `undefined`.
I thought that I can create new obj.map inside, but obj always string so it's impossible. Please, help me

Comment: If you rename the first arg in your map callback to `key` it might make things clearer. Ex: `.map((key, i) => <p key={i}>{this.state.data[key]}</p>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `Object.values` instead of `Object.keys`, then `obj` will be:

```js
{
  "id": "1",
  "data_2": "data_2",
  "data_3": true,
  "mg_gateway": "Another Object"
}
```

or you can do `this.state.data[key]` as in previous replies

```js
{Object.keys(this.state.data).map((key, i) => {
    return <p key={i}>{this.state.data[key]}</p>
})}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Object.keys` gives you only keys of object that is why you are only seeing the keys(uniqueId,uniqueId2) 
So if you want whole data along with uniqueId do 
`this.state.data.map(...your code);`
But I suspect you might get something like `[object]` so use 
`JSON.stringify` in map function.
Or you can simply replace 
`<p key={i}> {this.state.data[obj]}</p>`